# Does the latest intel c++ compiler support implicit move constructor and move assignment?

Tags: c++, c++11, icc

The latest intel C++ compiler is 14.0.1.139 or in intel parallel studio xe 2013 sp1 update 1. I am wondering if it supports implicit move constructor and move assignment. I tested it the following code, it doesn't seem to work.

The related article is [here](http://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/intel-composer-xe-2013-compilers-sp1-fixes-list) (search move constructor). It said it supports. But I cannot make it.

```
#include <memory>
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>

using namespace std;

class A
{
public:
    unique_ptr<int> m;
};

int main()
{
    A a;
    A b(std::move(a));
}
```

Compile it on windows as

```
icl main.cpp /Qstd=c++11
```

Errors

```
main.cpp
main.cpp(10): error #373: "std::unique_ptr<_Ty, _Dx>::unique_ptr(const
    std::unique_ptr<_Ty, _Dx>::_Myt &) [with _Ty=int, _Dx=std::default_delete<int>]"
    (declared at line 1447 of "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio
    11.0\VC\include\memory") is inaccessible unique_ptr<int> m;
                                                             ^
detected during implicit generation of "A::A(const A &)" at line 16
compilation aborted for main.cpp (code 2)
```

Basically the 2nd line in the main function `A b(std::move(a));` is looking for copy constructor `A::A(const A &)` other than move constructor `A::A(const A &&)`. That is usual when no implicit move constructors are generated. But the compiler said it support implicit move constructor. I am confused. Thanks.

Comment: You can look here http://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/c0x-features-supported-by-intel-c-compiler

Comment: The related article is http://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/intel-composer-xe-2013-compilers-sp1-fixes-list . It saids it supports. But I cannot make it.

Comment: What does "doesn't seem to work" mean?

Comment: It would improve your question if you add your operating system, how you call your compiler and what the actual error message is.

Answer (score 2):

Answer 1:

> On Windows environment when using Intel C++ compiler with Visual
>   Studio 2010* or 2012*, the C++11 features supported by Visual C++
>   2010/2012 are enabled by default. Use "/Qstd=c++11" to turn on the
>   support for all other cases.  On Linux or Mac OS X environment use
>   "-std=c++11".

From http://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/c0x-features-supported-by-intel-c-compiler

Answer 2 (guessing because of lack of information):
If the flag is set, you must include `<algorithm>` where `std::move` is defined.

Answer 3:
Your updated code compiles well with GCC and Clang. Maybe you have to define the move constructor explicitly:

```
#include <memory>
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>

using namespace std;

class A
{
public:
    // default constructor
    A()
    {}
    // move constructor
    A(A&& rhs)
    : m(std::move(rhs.m))
    {}

    unique_ptr<int> m;
};

int main()
{
    A a;
    A b(std::move(a));
}
```

Comment: I already set these options. The compiler still reports error.

Comment: I did not know and anybody else does still not know unless you edit your question and add this piece of information. See also my comment on your question what the error message is. Your question is not helpful and I'll downvote it.

Comment: Include <algorithm>. Still report error. Have you ever try it in intel c++? Any OS is fine. I am using windows.

Comment: Would you please, please update your question? What error? What is your exact call to the compiler? Could you update the program with the correct includes?
No, I did not try it with Intel myself, but I try to help you nevertheless.